# Getting BSON type of document field stored in MongoDB at mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongo-shell

I have two documents in my MongoDB database. They are (simplified):

```
{
    "_id" : "ONE",
    "items": [
        42,
        0
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : "TWO",
    "items": [
        0,
        0
    ]
}
```

They have been created by a client application (i.e. not using MongoDB shell) on which behavior I suspect (I mean, the application could have a bug and I'm trying to debug it).

I suspect that document `ONE` has the numbers in `items` encoded as 32-bits integer at BSON level (i.e. [BSON type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) 16) while in document `TWO` they are encoded in double (i.e. [BSON type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) 1)

I have tried to check it using usual `typeof` operator in JavaScript in the MongoDB shell but it seems they don't detect any difference:

```
> typeof db.entities.find({_id: "ONE"})[0].items[0]
number
> typeof db.entities.find({_id: "ONE"})[0].items[1]
number
> typeof db.entities.find({_id: "TWO"})[0].items[0]
number
> typeof db.entities.find({_id: "TWO"})[0].items[1]
number
```

Is there any precise way of knowing the BSON type of a given piece of the MongoDB documents from MongoDB shell?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `aggregate with $type`

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mh5ed8XuZYJ)

And your understanding is not quite exactly correct. Mongo by default considers the numbers as double.

See the example in the below, I forced to add an integer then it says it is integer. It doesn't print type number but type name

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$items" //Denormalized
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "x": {//All docs will have this - For demo purpose
        "$toInt": "11"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "t": {
        "$type": "$items" //Each element in the items - after denormalising
      },
      "t1": {
        "$type": "$x" //Type of newly added element
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I wonder if something simpler exists (something like `bsontype(<my field>)`) but of course, your way also works.

Comment: Unfortunately there is none. [Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#check-types-in-the-mongo-shell) it would say number for long double int. It would not say exact Bson type.

Comment: @fgalan the `$type` is exactly the `bysontype` function you are asking about. The complexity comes from your data being an array. If by "simpler" you mean fewer aggregation stages, you can use a single `$project` stage with [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to iterate the array and injecting type  of items but it would be even less readable.